# How to access function variable outside function

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to add the values of two functions together. What ways can i access a function variable so that it is visible to other functions. In the code snippet im specifically trying to work with the users input on the variable product_qty.

i get this error  print (Accounting_Menu.product_qty) AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'product_qty'

```
def main():

   Accounting_Menu()
   print (Accounting_Menu.product_qty)



def Accounting_Menu():
    print('COMPANY MESSAGE', '\n' *5)
    print('--> Quick Estimates <--')
    product_num = input('> Shoe Model(model number): ')
    product_size = input('> Shoe Size: ')
    product_qty = input('> Quantitiy: ')
    ship_zip_code = input('> Ship to Zip Code: ')
    return product_qty

main()
```

Comment: A function is not a class so the variables defined inside normally just exist while the function is executed. Since you're returning product_qty in your function "Accounting_Menu()" why aren't you just calling it and using the return value?

Answer (score 0):

Your function could return a dictionary containing the diffrent input from the user.
And use it from the main using the accounting_input['key_you_want_to_retrieve']

```
def main():
   accounting_input=Accounting_Menu()
   #print the quantity
   print(accounting_input['product_qty'])
   #print the size
   print(accounting_input['product_size'])

def Accounting_Menu():
    print('COMPANY MESSAGE', '\n' *5)
    print('--> Quick Estimates <--')
    product_num = input('> Shoe Model(model number): ')
    product_size = input('> Shoe Size: ')
    product_qty = input('> Quantitiy: ')
    ship_zip_code = input('> Ship to Zip Code: ')
    input_dictionary = {
        'product_num' : product_num,
        'product_size' : product_size,
        'product_qty' : product_qty,
        'input_dictionary' : ship_zip_code, 
    }
    return input_dictionary

main()
```